# java set Date fields in static method using Calendar

Tags: java, date, static, calendar

I want to set the fields of a given source date to a given target date using this method.

```
private static void setFields(final Date source, 
    final Date target, 
    final int ... fields)
{
    final Calendar sourceCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    sourceCalendar.setTime(source);

    final Calendar targetCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    targetCalendar.setTime(target);

    for(int field : fields)
        targetCalendar.set(field, sourceCalendar.get(field));
}
```

The minute of the target Date is not set. 
How am I suppose to set it if I don't want to break the reference by using.

```
target = targetCalendar.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the `target` date to the value in the `targetCalendar`, use:

```
target.setTime(targetCalendar.getTime().getTime());
```

Assuming that's what you were asking, your question was a little unclear.

Comment: Thanks! Oh my, so easy. That happens if Date and Calendar are f*** up. If I provide a date to a calendar and can set fields I think that the date should be manipulated through it as all java docs say. And not use Date.setTime(long) afterwards.